# Im getting this error, can anybody help `throw new Error('NO CHILD/MASTER EXISTS OR SUPPLIED CLUSTER_MANAGER_MODE IS INCORRECT');`

Tags: discord.js

Getting an error with discord.js sharding, Here is the shards.js files.

```js
const {
    ClusterManager
} = require("discord-hybrid-sharding");
require("dotenv").config();

const manager = new ClusterManager(`./index.js`, {
    totalShards: "auto",
    shardsPerClusters: 2,
    totalClusters: "auto",
    mode: "process",
    respawn: true,
    token: ""
});

manager.on("clusterCreate", (cluster) => {
    console.log(`Cluster ${cluster.id} created.`);
});




manager.spawn({
    timeout: -1
});
```

I have tried re-writing it all, reinstalling Discord-hybrid-sharding.